# Native-specific extensions with yarn workspaces and turborepo

Tags: react-native, vite, yarn-workspaces, turborepo, code-sharing

I'm setting up a project with shared packages with turborepo as such:

```
apps/
├─ app1/ (native)
├─ app2/ (web)

packages/
├─ utils/
│  ├─ storage/
│  │  ├─ index.web.ts
│  │  ├─ index.native.ts
│  ├─ index.ts
```

Storage here is a storage backend (like browser storage, `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` or [Expo secure storage](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/)). These have various degrees of support in different platforms, and I would like to use Expo secure storage whenever possible.

My goal is to create a set of shared packages with native specific extensions just like it is generally supported by [React native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#native-specific-extensions-ie-sharing-code-with-nodejs-and-web) projects.

My question is is this possible?

My fallback is to import `Platform` from react-native (and then use Vite alias for `'react-native': 'react-native-web'` in the web projects), and then do the import / branching manually.

But I was wondering if anyone has been able to do this with the tooling available for yarn workspaces / turborepo.